Clausulas if, else if, else y optimización de código
Es mi primera pregunta por aquí y puede que sea un poco obvia, pero me gustaría comprender esto correctamente. La duda es respecto a optimización de código y su uso sobre las clausulas if, else if e if.
¿Es necesario que exista un else, habiendo un if? He visto casos que no incluyen el else después del if. Esto imagino que es porque incluyen un return, ¿Esto optimiza la ejecución? Me resulta más visual usar el else. Un ejemplo de LeetCode:
class Solution {
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {

 if (root == null){
    return null;
 }

 TreeNode auxval = root.left;
 root.left = root.right;
 root.right = auxval;

 invertTree(root.left);
 invertTree(root.right);

 return root;
}

Otra duda, también he visto códigos que usan repetidamente if, en vez de usar else if. No entiendo en que casos podría ser esto más optimo que el usar jerarquías con else if y else.
Ejemplo:
if (edad < 18) {
    System.out.println("Eres menor de edad");
}
if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres adulto");
}
if (edad > 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres mayor de edad");
}

Y esto:
if (edad < 18) {
    System.out.println("Eres menor de edad");
} else if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres adulto");
} else {
   System.out.println("Eres mayor de edad");
}

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El primer caso al tener un return en el if, es lo mismo. En el segundo caso, no deberia ejecutar las otras comparaciones si estan en el else, cuando si son todos if, por mas que no entre, va a ejecutar las comparaciones. Computacionalmente, a esta altura, es lo mismo...

Si quieres tener un código óptimo tienes que fijarte en los algoritmos. Un buen algoritmo hará innecesario buscar/implementar hacks de bajo nivel como los que buscas. Además, hacks así no suelen ser portables.

IF sin ELSE
Se usa cuando no hay nada que hacer si la condición no se cumple. No afecta el rendimiento.
Ejemplo: descontar un contador sólo si es mayor que cero:
if contador > 0 {
    contador = contador - 1
     }

El ELSE lo vas a usar cuando debes ejecutar alguna acción para el caso que se cumpla la condición y otra para cuando no.
IF repetidos
Se usan cuando tienes que decidir entre alternativas independientes entre si.
Ejemplo: Tienes que calcular un monto, imprimirlo si es distinto de cero y aumentar un contador si excede 1000
if monto != 0 {
    print(monto)
    }

if monto > 1000 {
    montos_mayores = montos_mayores + 1
    }

Un ELSE no te sirve, pues pueden presentar ambas condiciones a la vez y por tanto, debes ejecutar ambas acciones.
IF ELSE IF
Se usa cuando vas afinando la selección de los datos.
Ejemplo: Imprimir niño, joven, adulto según su edad
IF edad <= 15 {
    print("niño")
    }
ELSE IF edad <= 21 {
    print("joven")
    }
ELSE
    print("adulto")

Cuando se pregunta "edad <= 21" ya sabes que la edad es mayor que 15.
Esta forma es más eficiente que múltiples IF, pues evita comparaciones innecesarias. Sin ELSE, quedaría así:
IF edad <= 15 {
    print("niño")
    }
IF edad > 15 and edad <= 21 {
    print("joven")
    }
IF edad > 21 {
    print("adulto")
    }

lo que es ineficiente: si es un niño de 10, igual tienes que evaluar los otros dos IF sin utilidad ninguna.
Optimizar los IF
Recuerda que la expresión del IF no es evaluada completamente; sólo se evalua hasta tener la seguridad del resultado
a = 1
b = 2
if a == 1 or b == 2 { ... }

En este caso, no se evaluara b, pues como la primera parte es verdadera (a == 1), la expresión con or sera cierta sin importar el valor de b.
Por tanto, puedes reordenar la expresión para que evalue el caso "más probable" primero y los más costosos después, aunque no se si valga la pena.

El primer caso, puede que a bajo nivel si ocurra una diferencia, porque al haber un else, va a tratar de mover esa parte del código a algo que se ejecute en una sección aparte, pero no te vas a dar cuenta a nivel código porque el costo computacional, a esta altura del partido, es nulo. Tal vez en un lenguaje mas bajo y que tengas que medir el rendimiento en ticks de llamadas pueda ser mas importante, pero dudo que llegues alguna vez a ese nivel.
El segundo caso, tiene un poquito mas de complejidad algorítmica, pero realmente nunca vas a notar la diferencia.
La cuestión es que acá:
if (edad < 18) {
    System.out.println("Eres menor de edad");
}
if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres adulto");
}
if (edad > 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres mayor de edad");
}

Estas haciendo siempre si o si 3 comparaciones. Aunque una haya dado verdadera, siempre vas a probar las otras 2.
El otro caso que describís, te ahorras comparaciones.
if (edad < 18) {
    System.out.println("Eres menor de edad");
} else if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 65) {
    System.out.println("Eres adulto");
} else {
   System.out.println("Eres mayor de edad");
}

Compara la primera, si es verdadera se ahorra el resto de las comparaciones. Si no, sigue...
Como nota, podrías todavía ahorrar un poco mas cambiando esta linea else if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 65) por esto else if (edad <= 65) { ya que si llegaste ahí, era porque el primero era falso, y entonces seguro es mayor que 17

Las explicaciones anteriores están bien, pero me quiero centrar en el tema de la optimización.
¿Cuál es mejor?

Primero que nada, aclarar que es mejor usar el orden if-elseif-else.
Esto debido a que al momento de leer el código, es una secuencia fácil de comprender y más lógica.
Además, esto aplica también al rendimiento, si una validación se cumple, el resto del código no lo hará, ahorrando tiempo de ejecución que del otro modo, sería innecesario.
¿Por que no usar 3 IF seguidos?

Al momento de realizar múltiples IF, tendremos que evaluarlos todos, ya sean verdaderos o falsos. Si esas condiciones las podemos juntar, optimizaremos el código, y su tiempo de ejecución, ¿de que mandera? Pues evaluando hasta la condición que es correcta, y no todas.
Un ejemplo de uso correcto y explicación de como se ignora el código (dependiendo siempre de las condiciones y resultados obvio)
# Ejemplo en Python
def validar_dado():
    valor = 3  # Valor simulado de un dado

    if valor == 1:
        print("Cara del dado: 1")  # Valor no es igual a 1, ignorado
    elif valor == 2:
        print("Cara del dado: 2")  # Valor no es igual a 2, ignorado
    elif valor == 3:
        print("Cara del dado: 3")  # Valor SI es 3, se imprime
    elif valor == 4:
        print("Cara del dado: 4")  # Ignorado
    elif valor == 5:
        print("Cara del dado: 5")  # Ignorado
    elif valor == 6:
        print("Cara del dado: 6")  # Ignorado

Si en este ejemplo, fueran todos los IF seguidos, todos tendrían que ser evaluados, dando un total de 6 revisiones. Incluso más si es que agregamos otras condiciones.
Pero como hemos agrupado las condicionales, con el uso de if-elseif (elif en python), solamente se evalúa hasta la condición correcta, y el resto, se ignora. Ahorrandonos, al menos durante la revisión, 3 verificaciones.
